# Is there a way to transfer a conversation from Dialogflow CX to agents on Amazon Connect?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx, amazon-connect

From what I've read online, Amazon Connect wants to promote usage of Amazon Lex and does not offer a Bring Your Own Bot model. Does anyone know of a working solution to leverage a Google Dialogflow CX bot and escalate to agents on Amazon Connect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same requirement give the capabilities of DFCX (Voice) vs Lex, our customer requires DFCX integration with Amazon Connect. Is Amazon Connect and Voice and Chat bot integration a walled garden that prevents 3rd party integrations?